# Installing the 'mathabx' package

Tags: errors, miktex, windows, texworks

I'm trying to install the `mathabx` package and am having some troubles. I am using MixTek 2.9 and running TexWorks. I have tried typing `\usepackage{mathabx}` into the console as usual before I `\maketitle` and start the paper etc. However, it keeps saying:

```
Unfortunately, the package mathabx could not be installed.Please check the log file:
C:/Users/mouse_000/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-pdftex.log
======================================================================


! LaTeX Error: File `mathabx.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

When I type `\usepackage{mathabx}` it prompts me to install the package and then gives me a list of sites (with countries listed in a separate column) that I can install it however trying a few of them it doesn't seem to work. it. Any help is appreciated on this.

Comment: Did you install it with MiKTeX  Package  Manager?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet. I will try this tomorrow if I can and will let you know. Thank you for this advice.

Comment: Oh, btw, don't forget to install `mathabxtype1` too, if you don't want to have bitmap fonts, and (probably) to run `updmap.exe` from the command line, so the system knows *where* the type 1 fonts are.